# How to avoid numeric come first alignment Issue while converting string data to json array through Json Parse in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, jsonparser

Here is the sample code of returning string data from ajax

```
Result = "[
{"ProductCode":"0000001",
"ProductName":"BRINJAL LONG (GREEN)",
"HQ":"43.00",
"1104":"0.00",
"4758":"20.00",
"5379":"23.00",
"964":"2.00",
"ActualQty":"0.00",
"IsCheck":"True"}
]"
```

I am converting string to json array through Json parse sample code here

`var myproduct = []; myproduct = JSON.parse(Result);`

Actually i need output like same as string return alignment order but i am getting like this numeric comes first. kindly give some advice how to avoid this auto alignment

```
'{964: "2.00", 
   1104: "0.00",
   4758: "20.00",
   5379: "23.00", 
   ProductCode: "0000001", 
   ProductName: "BRINJAL LONG (GREEN)",
   HQ: "43.00", 
   ActualQty :"0.00",
   IsCheck : "True"
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

you should change your data shape, JavaScript `JSON.parse()` doesn't let you to control that.

1. a silly solution is to add a counter to the key names. it's bad because later you need to do some string manipulation to remove the counter

   ```
   Result = "[
   {"1.ProductCode":"0000001",
   "2.ProductName":"BRINJAL LONG (GREEN)",
   "3.HQ":"43.00",
   "4.1104":"0.00",
   "5.4758":"20.00",
   "6.5379":"23.00",
   "7.964":"2.00",
   "8.ActualQty":"0.00",
   "9.IsCheck":"True"}
   ]"
   ```
2. or change the value part and add an `order` item. this way you can sort things again using that `order` value

   ```
   Result = "[
   {
       "ProductCode":{
           "value": "0000001"
           "order": 1
       },
       "ProductName":{
           "value" : "BRINJAL LONG (GREEN)",
           "order" : 2
       },
      ....
   }]"
   ```
3. or a better solution would be to send an array of single key-value object. this way the parse of the json, will keep the order of the array. then each item has key and value.

   ```
   Result = "[
       {"ProductCode":"0000001"},
       {"ProductName":"BRINJAL LONG (GREEN)"},
       {"HQ":"43.00"},
       {"1104":"0.00"},
       {"4758":"20.00"},
       {"5379":"23.00"},
       {"964":"2.00"},
       {"ActualQty":"0.00"},
       {"IsCheck":"True"}
   ]"
   ```
4. a much better solution will be to set a key for each item, it's much easier to work with without need to use `Object.Keys()` to get the key value.

   ```
   Result = "[
       { "key" : "ProductCode", "value" :"0000001"},
       { "key" : "ProductName", "value" :"BRINJAL LONG (GREEN)"},
       { "key" : "HQ", "value" :"43.00"},
       { "key" : "1104", "value" :"0.00"},
       { "key" : "4758", "value" :"20.00"},
       { "key" : "5379", "value" :"23.00"},
       { "key" : "964", "value" :"2.00"},
       { "key" : "ActualQty", "value" :"0.00"},
       { "key" : "IsCheck", "value" :"True"}
   ]"
   ```

but this question just give me a hint that your problem is somewhere else. because you are relying on the order of the data. this way of coding, your code will fail when one of these items go missing, or some more get add to it.